# Get KML region info from address and kmz

Tags: kmz, region

I know nothing about GIS so I could be using the wrong words here.

I've got a KMZ file which shows the congressional districts of the US. I want to be able to enter a street address, and then get back which congressional district I'm in.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to get started with this?

Comment: Geocoding is likely the right term. try https://www.imapbuilder.com/customization/google_map_zipcode_search_for_congressional_district.php

Comment: Another one you can pull and bring it in to your KML viewer online http://kmlviewer.nsspot.net/